# Php, openserver и composer: как установить стороннюю библиотеку

Tags: php, composer, openserver

Не являюсь знатоком композера, а тут потребовалось в проект локально установить стороннюю библиотеку. Нашел в openserver консоль, в ней запустил `composer require sebastian/diff`. Установка вроде как прошла, я хочу запустить пример, пишу в index.php согласно инструкции

```
<?php
use SebastianBergmann\Diff\Differ;

$differ = new Differ;
print $differ->diff('foo', 'bar');
```

а в ответ

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SebastianBergmann\Diff\Differ' not found in Z:\z.ru\index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in Z:\z.ru\index.php on line 17
```

подскажите, плиз, что мне надо сделать, я конечно по незнанию что-то, видимо, не то творю, но не пойму, куда копать и где разбираться

спасибо

Comment: 1. убедиться что реально стоит: `ls -la vendor/sebastian/diff`. 2. нужно подключить автолодер композера. все фрейморки это делают из коробки. если у вас не фреймворк - то добавьте `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` после `use` - только поправьте путь, может быть не нужно `..`

Comment: Вот оно, мое незнание! `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` это и есть решение! Огромное спасибо!